# How to solve $c=x^{a+1}\left(\frac{1}{x}b\right)^{a}-x^{a+1}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, roots, radicals

I have almost isolated $x$ in the equation:

$\displaystyle \frac{\frac{z}{\ln\left(2\right)}at^{a}z^{a}\left(z+1-t\right)}{\left(z+1-t\right)^{a+1}}=x^{a+1}\left(\left(\frac{tz}{x\left(z+1-t\right)}\right)^{a}-1\right)$

Which may be simplified to the general expanded form (where $a,b$ & $c$ are constants):

$c=x^{a+1}\left(\frac{1}{x}b\right)^{a}-x^{a+1}$

How would I go about solving for $x$ here? I have been stuck for a while and would grateful for any help.

Comment: Is there any more context to this problem? Because I played around with the equality, seems it comes down to $x^{a+1}-b^ax+c=0$, and you're trying to then find roots of that $a+1$st degree polynomial, which shouldn't be necessarily be possible (that is, finding a closed form of the roots in general).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was trying to find when $\frac{d}{dx}\left(2^{\frac{x}{z}}\left(\left(\frac{t}{x-\frac{x}{z}\left(t-1\right)}\right)^{a}-1\right)\right)=0$. The function has extreme points (however I don't know if these may be solved). There may also be another way to approach this that I haven't considered.

Comment: Are $a, b, c$ integers?

Comment: There is no closed form solution for general $a,b,c$ as I point out under Jbag1212's answer. You can however estimate the solutions using numerical methods without too much difficulty since the extrema of $x^n-cx$ are easy to find, which bounds the possible solutions to your equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$c=x^{a+1} (\frac{1}{x} b)^a - x^{a+1}$$
$$c=x^{a+1} (\frac{1}{x^a} b^a) - x^{a+1}$$
$$c=x  b^a - x^{a+1}$$
Let $x=by$ (the problem when $b=0$ can be done)
$$c=(by)b^a - (by)^{a+1}$$
$$c=yb^{a+1} - b^{a+1} y^{a+1}$$
Let $d=a+1$
$$\frac{c}{b^d} = y - y^d.$$
$$y^d -y  +f =0$$
Even if $d$ is an integer, there is no way in general to invert $d$th order polynomials, however there may be a technique for this specific polynomial. You can say that there *is* a solution if $d$ is odd ($a$ is even).

Comment: For general $d,f$ there is no closed form solution using radicals (already with $d=5$ one can see Bring radicals are needed). Using Lagrange inversion theorem does however give a series expansion for a solution which happens to be a generalized hypergeometric function.

Comment: Thank you everybody. In my original equation, $a=\frac{\ln2}{\ln t}$. So, $a+1>1$ when $t>1$, but it is in the set of real numbers. Given this is the case, how would I apply Lagrange inversion to find a series expansion (as raised by @SimplyBeautifulArt)?

Comment: @UNOwen This exact form as seen in the answer above is on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem#Example).